# How do i find the most frequent facility in SQL

Tags: sql, database

Currently, my table comprises two - Facility table [Facility table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf629.png) and Booking table [Booking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX75t.png)

How do I list the most used popular facility used by the members in 2017?

1. Year has to be 2017
2. The most frequent facility used each month

After trying to do

[This is what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI8nA.png)

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime) AS 'Month', 
    f.FacilityDesc AS 'MOST FREQUENT'
FROM
    Booking b
INNER JOIN 
    Facility f ON b.FacilityID = f.FacilityID
WHERE
    YEAR(b.BookingStartDateTime) = 2017
GROUP BY
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime), f.FacilityDesc
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime) DESC
```

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: And how you define the most popular facility?

Comment: The most popular facility is defined as having the highest count in a month ( used the most)

Comment: Then why don't you use `count(*)`?

Comment: What do u mean by use count(*) ?

Comment: How can you calculate *the highest count* without `count`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work.

```
select Month, 'Most Frequent' from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by Month order by Frequency desc) rnk from (

SELECT 
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime) AS 'Month', 
    f.FacilityDesc AS 'MOST FREQUENT',
    count(*) as 'Frequency'
FROM
    Booking b
INNER JOIN 
    Facility f ON b.FacilityID = f.FacilityID
WHERE
    YEAR(b.BookingStartDateTime) = 2017
GROUP BY
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime), f.FacilityDesc
) rnk
) a where rnk = 1
order by month desc
```

Added a non-window function version, you need to do inner joins or where exists method to get your result

```
with rnk as (
    SELECT 
        MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime) AS 'Month', 
        f.FacilityDesc AS 'MOST FREQUENT',
        count(*) as 'Frequency'
    FROM
        Booking b
    INNER JOIN 
        Facility f ON b.FacilityID = f.FacilityID
    WHERE
        YEAR(b.BookingStartDateTime) = 2017
    GROUP BY
        MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime), f.FacilityDesc
)

select Month, 'Most Frequent' from rnk where exists(
    select Month, freq from (
        select Month, max(Frequency) freq from rnk group by Month
    )  a where a.Month = rnk.Month and a.freq = rnk.Frequency
)
order by Month desc
```

Comment: Will work well. The only special case is when there are multiple facilities tied in first place, in which case this query will [randomly] pick one of them. Upvoting anyway.

Comment: In that case just use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` of course as long OP db support window functions.

Comment: As Windowed Aggregates are calculated *after* aggregation you can nest the count directly in row_number/rank: `Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY MONTH ORDER BY Count(*) DESC)`

Comment: If I am using Microsoft SQL server how should i code?

Comment: i am still quite new to sql and still isnt very familar to most of the concept

Comment: Is there an easier way to code this without using RANK but TOP instead?

Comment: Rank function or Row_number function is available in SQL server

Comment: I got an error with the code you send me, at the second last statement

Comment: select Month, 'Most Frequent' from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by Month order by Frequency desc) rank from (

SELECT 
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime) AS 'Month', 
    f.FacilityDesc AS 'MOST FREQUENT',
    count(*) as 'Frequency'
FROM
    Booking b
INNER JOIN 
    Facility f ON b.FacilityID = f.FacilityID
WHERE
    YEAR(b.BookingStartDateTime) = 2017
GROUP BY
    MONTH(b.BookingStartDateTime), f.FacilityDesc
) rank
)
WHERE rank = 1
order by month desc

Comment: when entered this, i got the error of Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
@QianboWang

Comment: @Eric I updated the original answer, I forgot to add a table alias in the nested select statements

Comment: Is there a possibility to do this query without using partition, rank, and row number @QianboWang

Comment: @Eric Added a non-window function version to my initial answer. But the most efficient way should be using window functions...